# content of my xml is deleting when im adding a root to my xml document

Tags: php, arrays, xml, root, createelement

I'm creating an XLM document and then trying to add a root :

```
 **function makeTransaction()** {
            $arr = [
        "client_id" => $this->client_id,
        "client_name" => $this->client_name,
        "client_password" => $this->client_password,
        "sender_first_name" => "Marie",
        "sender_last_name" => "Dupont",
        "sender_address" => "Washington Street",
        "sender_city" => "New York",
        "sender_country" => "USA",
        ];
        $myxml = $this->arrayToXml($arr, "<validate_transaction/>");
        }
    
    
     **function arrayToXml($array, $rootElement = null, $xml = null)** {    
        $_xml = $xml;
        if ($_xml === null) {
          $_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($rootElement !== null ? $rootElement :
'<root/>');      
        }            
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {                
          if (is_array($v)) {            
            arrayToXml($v, $k, $_xml->addChild($k));                
          } else {                  
            $_xml->addChild($k, $v);                
          }   
        *$doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('Money'));            
        $domnode = dom_import_simplexml($_xml);               
        $doc->documentElement->appendChild($doc->importNode($domnode));          
         $_xml= simplexml_import_dom($doc);
         print($_xml->asXML());*               
        }
```

I dont  understand, im success to get the xml document at the beggining but one i'm adding the last part of the function to add the root ("money'), i only have this result:

```
<money>
<validate_transaction>
<validate_transaction/>
 </money>
```

and everything inside validate transaction disapear.
Could you help me please

Comment: The output shown doesn't come from this script. XML is case sensitive.  You have 'Money' in the script and 'money' in the output.